# SQL Server: delete users that has single quotes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to delete users from the system and the search is based on their email. However, due to some weird validation, some of the users have single quotes and a wildcard (%) character in emails.

When I try to delete the user, its throwing out an error, because of single quotes and other weird characters. I can directly clean up in database, however, I wanted to see if I can search with all that junk in their email and still delete the users directly from the app

For ex:

```
DELETE FROM Customers
WHERE Email = 'test@yahoo.com'@countag%and1=1''
```

Comment: Can you give some more details? Do you have a list of email addresses (With special characters) that you have to use, to locate the records and then delete them? If so, are these addresses in another table or will they be passed to your SQL / Script? Or it is something like a user will enter 1 email address through your UI that can contain special characters and your SQL script has to use that address to locate the record and delete records matching that email address.

Comment: yes, its the latter part, where a user enter email address through web app, which needs to be passed on to delete statement matching that email address

Answer (score 1):

It's ok for the wild card character since you are not matching for patterns, but for single quotes, you need to double to escape it.

```
DELETE FROM Customers
WHERE Email = 'test@yahoo.com''@countag%and1=1'''
                      --     ^ this           ^ and this.
```

Comment: Does that mean I have to search for quotes first in email and if there is any, make it double? How is that done in SQL statement?

Comment: So like do a Replace function in Delete statement?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest workaround is to use double quotes, so won't have to worry about embedded single quotes:

```
DELETE FROM Customers
WHERE Email = "test@yahoo.com'@countag%and1=1"
```

Comment: But SQL server doesn't like double quotes

Comment: @user2675939 I didn't notice the title hint that it was SQLServer. I'll add the tag to your question.

Answer (score 0):

you could try

```
delete from customers where charindex('''', email) > 0
```

to delete all customers with an email address that contains at least one single quote ... or maybe do a select first and check the result

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE UsersToDelete

CREATE TABLE UsersToDelete
(
    id        INT IDENTITY
   ,email     VARCHAR(500)
)


INSERT INTO UsersToDelete
  (
    -- id -- this column value is auto-generated
    email
  )
SELECT 'test@yahoo.com''@countag%and1=1''' AS email
UNION
SELECT 'bill.gates@microsoft.com'
UNION
SELECT 'user2675939@stackoverflow.com'
UNION
SELECT 'iamkarlson''''''@google.com'

SELECT utd.id
      ,utd.email
      ,CASE 
            WHEN (SUBSTRING(email ,CHARINDEX('''' ,email ,0) +1 ,1) <>'''' 
            OR SUBSTRING(REVERSE(email) ,CHARINDEX('''' ,REVERSE(email) ,0) +1 ,1) <>'''')
                 AND email LIKE '%''%'
                THEN 1
            WHEN SUBSTRING(email ,CHARINDEX('''' ,email ,0) +1 ,1) =''''
                 AND SUBSTRING(REVERSE(email) ,CHARINDEX('''' ,REVERSE(email) ,0) +1 ,1) =''''
                 AND email LIKE '%''%' 
                THEN 0
            ELSE 0
       END            AS [Contains]
      ,SUBSTRING(email ,CHARINDEX('''' ,email ,0) +1 ,1)
      ,SUBSTRING(REVERSE(email) ,CHARINDEX('''' ,REVERSE(email) ,0) +1 ,1)
FROM   UsersToDelete     utd
```